# Sharing Jabber chat session between multiple clients

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm using Jitsi on client side and ejabberd on server.

It seems that the chat sessions are specific to clients, i.e. if I'm logged in to the same account from 2 different clients, there will be 2 separate sessions, and one can't see what's happening in another.

Is it possible to share the sessions for the same account on all clients? Like Skype or GTalk.
If yes, is it a server configuration or client?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're looking for is [XEP-0280 Message Carbons](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html). Basically the server takes care of relaying the chat to all of your online resources so that you have the same chat session across all devices.

You even get chatstates from all of your other resources so you can infer whether or not you should show an unread IM notification to the user on your resource or not. You'll need client and server support for this, and it looks like ejabberd has implemented it via [this module](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/mod_message_carbon).

Comment: Thank you! I've actually moved to prosody since then and installed XEP-280 carbons module as well, which is reported in log, but no effect.. I'll try ejabberd again with this module.

Comment: @Unirgy: Jitsi does not seem to support XEP-0280. Try Gajim instead.

Comment: @tapyngo: Thanks, is it normal that gajim.org TLS certificate is invalid? I'm uncertain if I should download anything from there :)

Comment: It is signed by CA-Cert, so unfortunately, yes, the warning is normal. CA-Cert is a free certification authority, but they are really doing a good job at verifying authenticity of identity (for class 3 certificates). But they are not trusted by default by a lot of OS and browser. You can download their root certificates [here](https://www.cacert.org/index.php?id=3)